# When reset-btn is clicked, calculate-btn stops and then does not work

Tags: jquery, css

When `reset-btn` is clicked, the calculation stops after being started, but doesn't work afterward. How can I use `restart-calculate-btn`? Click `reset-btn` and stop `calculate-btn` after when both options get selected `calculate-btn` is animated... `calculate-btn` is always opacity `1`.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $(".choose").change(function(){
        count++;
        if(count ==2){
        blink();
        }
    });
    function blink() {
        $(".calculate-btn").animate({
        opacity: '0'
        }, function(){
        $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
        }, blink);
        });
    }
    $(".reset-btn").click(function(){
        $(".calculate-btn").stop();
    });
   });

 <form>
   <select class="form-contol">
  <option value='0'> Select</option>
  <option value='1'> 1</option>
  <option value='2'> 2</option>
  <option value='3'> 3</option>
   </select>

 <select class="form-contol">
  <option value='0'> Select</option>
  <option value='1'> 1</option>
  <option value='2'> 2</option>
  <option value='3'> 3</option>
 </select>
 <button type="button" class="calculate-btn">Claculate</button>
 <button type="reset" class="reset-btn">Reset</button>
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/3jLAZ/11/

Comment: Can you explain more? question is not clear.

Comment: yes calculate-btn stop when rest-btn is click next choset option is seletec no work calculat button animate how use

Comment: like this : http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/25/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use .stop() to stop the animation.

```
$("#reset").click(function(){
    $(".calculate-btn").stop()
    .css('opacity' , 1);
});
```

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/3jLAZ/28/

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: you answer is no work, i wanted bothselected option start animate cal-butoon and reset-btn click stop calculate-btn...

Comment: thaks your answer next.. slove my problem

Comment: @ ကစၥပ နဒီ  let me get this straight..when you click on an option your calc button should start animating and when reset is clicked it should stop. right??

Comment: thats exactly what i did

Comment: my mean 1.calculate-btn is animate. 2. reset-btn is click calculate-btin is anaimate stop(calculat-btn is opcity:1;).   3. and the calculate-btn is start animate.

Comment: two selecte is selected start animate button

Comment: 1.calculate-btn is animate. 2. reset-btn is click calculate-btin is anaimate stop(calculat-btn is opcity:1;). 3. and the calculate-btn is start animate.

Comment: it starts animating again after 500 sec

Comment: and one selectbox is selected animate i dont like this, i mean two selectbox is two select button animate

Comment: you want to animate only when both select boxes are selected?

Comment: i want there action 1. two slecet is selected 2. restbutton click stop calcultebutton 3. start animate calculatebutton opacity 1;

Comment: hello friends.do you help me.how use stack over account enable. my account is not ask so i am very tired...

Answer (score 1):

Use following code

```
$(".form-contol").change(function(){
blink();
});

var blink = function() {
$(".calculate-btn").animate({
    opacity: '0'
    }, function(){
    $(this).animate({
        opacity: '1'
    }, blink);
  });
};

$(".reset-btn").click(function(){
 $(".calculate-btn").stop().animate({opacity:1});
});
```

Comment: both select option getselected start animate calculate-btn

Comment: do you understand about my answer, my friend.

Comment: 1.calculate-btn is animate. 2. reset-btn is click calculate-btin is anaimate stop(calculat-btn is opcity:1;). 3. and the calculate-btn is start animate.